# Poured fondant that stays liquid

Tags: candy, consistency, fondant

I need help regarding poured fondant - to be precise, I would like to have it more on the liquid side.

I plan to use it as a chocolate bar filling, that is why I am asking :)

The recipe I use in general:
6 cups confectioners' sugar, 1/4 cup water, 1 tablespoon light corn syrup.

I melt them over low heat until completely blended, and then usually let it cool down and glaze cakes.

Can this recipe be modified so it stays somewhat liquid?
Maybe like a creme egg filling?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you add some form of fat into your recipe. Fat is what gives foods a smooth creamy texture. Some ideas to use are butter and coconut oil.

Comment: Cream would work well too, a la ganache.